# Prevent a form field from displaying

Tags: python, html, django, aptana

I have a form and want that the *user* field should not be displayed.

models.py

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    question=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_date=models.DateTimeField('date created')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s%s" %(self.question,self.created_date)
```

form.py

```
class QuestionsForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Questions
        widgets = {
            'question': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add question here'})
        }
         exclude=('user',)
```

I tried *exclude* but the field still appears.
how to do it??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it should work actually:
Just do some minute checks:

1.exclude should be part of class Meta

2.make that exclude from tuple to list , (not sure if it helps)

3.or instead of exclude try giving fields = (#some fields names, )

Hope this works ..

Answer (score 0):

Use this in views:

```
form.fields['name_of_field'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

or you can handle it in in HTML by input hidden tag:

```
<input type='hidden'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your model form in such a way.

```
QuestionsForm(ModelForm):
        user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                         widget=forms.HiddenInput())
        class Meta:
            model = Questions
```

Comment: i am getting a error that forms not defined when run syncdb. What to do.Pls help.

Comment: Could you please provide the error log, and please verify you import ModelForm from django forms .